# Spinner automatically change the style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I changes the button style but it also changed the style of spinner. See the image it looks like [![Image after change the style of button named start test.Spinner look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create custom style for spinner and apply it.

Below is the example,

spinner_item.xml:
Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

Comment: No i think i could not explained you problem. I changed the button style using setTextAppearance(res id) . You can see the button start test  just below Spinner. Before change the style of button spinner look good as you normally see but when i changed the button style then it automatically change the look of spinner. As you can see at image that i provided.

Comment: You changed the style in button xml or style.xml

Comment: I changed the style at runtime.

Comment: I created two style for button . And changing it at runtime .